# spring-data-cassandra, Cassandra storing List<Integer> as field

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have problem storing field of List as field of my table in cassandra database.

I'm using spring-data-cassandra, version 1.4.1.RELEASE.

My model contains:

```
@Column
@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.LIST)
private List<Integer> somedata;
```

I would like to auto create my db tables with SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED Schema action in my config class:

```
@Override
public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;
}
```

It tries to create table, but following exception occurs:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: expected 1 of typed arguments for the property  'somedata' type is 'interface java.util.List' in the entity <my class here>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, found solution after digging into spring-data-cassandra source:

```
@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.LIST, typeArguments = { DataType.Name.FLOAT } )
private List<Float> position;
```

You need to add typeArguments, to specify DataType of generic type. Exception mentioned in question is thrown when invalid number of those typeArguments is passed. In my case there was 0 and 1 is required.

@Column annotation proved to be not required here.

Comment: Please be aware that empty collection type values are `null` as they are returned this way from Cassandra. Therefore your field `position` will be `null` as well if the list has no elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to provide CassandraType annotation over the field as long as you are using primitive or Wrapper type objects.
Following works fine for me.

```
@PrimaryKey
int id;
String name;
int num;
List<Integer> marks;
```

I am using spring-data-cassandra with version 1.4.2.RELEASE.
Please update if you still face the issue.